SQL developer not show results if they match certain criteria
I'm trying to make a oracle sql developer query to return items which only meet certain criteria. The problem I'm facing is that one item can have multiple conditions and based on those conditions I need to filter out the results. So it needs some sort of array or select inside a select?
The data set looks like this:



ItemNo
Condition
Date




1234
A
9999-99-99


1234
B
9999-99-99


1234
B
9999-99-99


5555
A
9999-99-99


5555
B
2024-12-10



Now I need to return Items only that DO NOT have condition B assigned to the item only if the condition B date is not 9999-99-99 or more than condition A date.
so In essence item 1234 should not be returned as it has 2x condition B with date which is equal to condition A and the date is also 9999-99-99.
Item 5555 should be returned as even though it has condition B, the date is less than condition A.
Currently I have this:
select ItemNo from DataSet where Condition not in 'B' and Date between :a and :b

I was thinking of creating a query to select all the Items without checking for condition and then maybe nesting it into another select which would check if each item has multiple conflicting conditions but not sure if it's the right approach.

Can you put what you've tried on there.

Yes, sorry forgot to add that.
Currently I have this (simplified for example):
select ItemNo from DataSet where Condition not in 'B' and Date between :a and :b
So this returns me ItemNo 1234 and 5555 rows with just condition A when it shouldn't return 1234 at all since it has condition B with conflicting dates.
I was thinking of creating a query to select all the Items without checking for condition and then maybe nesting it into another select which would check if each item has multiple conflicting conditions but not sure how to approach that.

Please edit your question to add additional details, with code as formatted text.

9999-99-99 isn't a (valid) date. Which data type are you using here?

@jarlh it's just an example number. Real would always be 2200-01-01 for both conditions if the condition is valid. Otherwise it would be 2024-12-10 lets say, which means that the condition is no longer valid today.

I am not sure, if I have understood the task. Is it simply: "Look at each item; if for its newest date there is only condition A then select that item"? If this is not the task, then please be very specific about the rules: when to show an item, when to dismiss it. Are there just the two conditions A and B or are there more? Why do you mention that pseudo date 9999-99-99 (which you then say is actually 2200-01-01)? Does it somehow change the task?


Condition B doesn't exist for the ItemNo.
Or, if Condition B does exist, its date (DateB) is not 9999-12-31(any other date), and is less than the date of Condition A (DateA).

Fiddle
SELECT ItemNo
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ItemNo,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Condition = 'A' THEN Date1 END) AS DateA,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Condition = 'B' THEN Date1 END) AS DateB
    FROM test
    GROUP BY ItemNo
) conditions
WHERE (
    (DateB IS NULL)  
    OR 
    (DateB != TO_DATE('9999-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND DateB < DateA)  
);

Output


Thank @samhita this is more or less what I was having in mind. It seems to work fine in sql fiddle when I setup the data to better represent my real dataset and I modified it to use like and not like instead of = but for some reason in my real case it does not work the same way.
https://dbfiddle.uk/rWPHgyiP

Thanks @AidasDem, I looked at your dataset in the fiddle,I think it returns correct(?) ItemNo 5555 will not be returned as both condition A% and B% has max date as 2200-01-01 and the condition dateA > dateB fails as both are equal now.

You can use a HAVING clause and check that there are either no rows with a condition of 'B' or that the MAXimum date for rows with condition of 'A' are less than the MINimum date for rows with condition of 'B':
SELECT itemno
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY itemno
HAVING COUNT(CASE condition WHEN 'B' THEN dt END) = 0
OR     MAX(CASE condition WHEN 'B' THEN dt END)
         < MIN(CASE condition WHEN 'A' THEN dt END)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (itemNo, Condition, dt) AS
SELECT 1234, 'A', DATE '9999-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'B', DATE '9999-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'B', DATE '9999-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5555, 'A', DATE '9999-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5555, 'B', DATE '2024-12-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6789, 'A', DATE '2024-12-10' FROM DUAL;

Note: 9999-99-99 is not a valid date.
Outputs:



ITEMNO




5555


6789



fiddle

thanks for the suggestions @MT0 and @samhita both are very good although they didn't work in my case as expected, I suspect due to have multiple tables connected to retrieve the data.
In the end what worked was using a simple not in which filtered out all items that have condition B and only selected what's left, for example:
Select
column1
column2
column3

from 
table.a,
table.b,
table.c
and
a.field1 not in 
(select 
a.field1

from
from 
table.a,
table.b,
table.c
where
a.field1.=b.field2
and c.field1=b.field1
and
condition like 'B'
)

